# Is it ok to remove a loss function term by setting it's loss_weights in model.compile to zero in Keras?

Tags: keras, keras-layer, tf.keras

My total loss function has three terms:

`L = λ1*L1 + λ2*L2 + λ3*L3`

And all the λ are set by `loss_weights{"λ1":1, "λ2":1, "λ2":1}` when I run [model.compile](https://keras.io/models/model/#compile).
Now I want to remove the `L1` term.
Is it ok if I change `loss_weights{"λ1":0, "λ2":1, "λ2":1}` in loss_weights instead of removing the output of L1 term in my model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should be fine, it will cancel gradients from that part of the loss. This trick is commonly done in object detection losses, so we know it works.

Comment: But after the I set the loss_weight to 0.0. That loss term is still having a value?

Comment: @koha what do you mean having a value?

Comment: Sorry for replying late. I mean when I set "λ1":0. The L1: keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred) is still having constant value (ex:0.22 ) because of the y_true. So I think L1 still affects the total loss even when I set the λ1 = 0. Pls correct me if I understand the wrong way

Comment: @koha Individual losses are computed and only used for display, when the weights are used for the total weighted loss (the one called literally loss in the keras progress bar), and this is the one used for gradient computation. You can check this by setting lambda to a non-zero value and seeing that the loss is in a different range.